# MKLocalSearch with wildcard

Tags: ios, ios6, mapkit

Is there a way to get all places of an given region?
I would like to offer the user a list of all existing venues in a region when he taps the screen, but I only found ways to use `MKLocalSearch` with a specific search query string.

Comment: What kind of venues are you talking about?

Comment: Basicaly it's an location based reminder - I would love to suggest any venues on base of the user's tap on the map. Like the "share location" feature of WhatsApp...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to get all places of an given region?

There's nothing built into MapKit or Core Location that provides that kind of information. Your best bet would be to look for a suitable data source for the kinds of "venues" that you're interested in, such as Google, Yelp!, FourSquare, yellow pages, etc.